# In Azure DevOps, how do I prevent failing unit tests from failing the build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline which contains a build task, a publish task, and a test task. There are some unit tests that fail, which is causing the whole build to fail.

How can I prevent this? I don't want to have to require 100% of my unit tests to pass just for the build to succeed...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the parameter "Continue on error" = true:

[image]

In yaml:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a visual editor for my pipeline, only YAML, and when I add `continueOnError: true` to my test task, I get this error: "Unexpected property continueOnError"...

Comment: Can you share your yaml?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://gist.github.com/ekolis/9a3a31b5d6a7c3432b10b19401dc977d - I added the `continueOnError: true` to the test task at the end but it's not showing up now because I didn't want to save it with errors.

Comment: @ekolis Please check my update, you need to put in the line of the `inputs` and not in the line of the `platform` and `configuration`

Comment: Thanks, now I get a yellow "!" icon for the build status and the build continues running after the tests fail! :)

Comment: Unfortunately as soon as you set `continueOnError: true` failing tests will not fail the step or the build so you have to use something like `task: PublishTestResults@2` with the `failTaskOnFailedTests: true` option to fail the build. Now OP wants the build to not fail but if you DO want it to fail but you DO want following steps to run (e.g. publishtestresults) you have to do as I suggested.

Comment: It seems the "continueOnError" option doesn't exist anymore, at least not in Visual Studio Tests

Answer (score 0):

condition: succeededOrFailed()